# Access name column elements from a Sharepoint list using REST

Tags: javascript, rest, sharepoint

I am using the following code to pull back items from a SharePoint List

```
        function getItems(url) {    
          return $.ajax({
          url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + url,
          type: "GET",
          headers: {
            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                   }
          });
        }

        getItems( "/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('Reporting%   
         20Listing')/Items" ).done(function(data){
         data.d.results.forEach(function(item){  
         console.log( item.ID, item.Title, item.ApprovalName, 
         item.ApprovalDate );
            });
          });
```

This is working fine except `item.ApprovalName` is not returning any value.

Do I need to somehow reference which element of the `ApprovalName` array that I want? I've looked through several reference but don't see an example.

Comment: What's the field type for ApprovalName? It should output object if it's an array, and get value by ApprovalName[index].property

Comment: In SharePoint 'List Settings' the field is set to 'Person or Group'. I ran the browser debugger and it looks like 'ApprovalNameId' is being returned, not an array. so if I change 'item.ApprovalName' to 'item.ApprovalNameId' it returns the ID successfully, however, I need to get the display name which is what's actually shown in the sharepoint list. When I click view source on the edit form, I can see the various elements of the ApprovalName array but the REST call is only returning the ID it seems

Answer (score 0):

Sample demo to expand multiuser field.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(GetListItems, "sp.js");
        function GetListItems() {
            var apiPath = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('MyList3')/items?$select=Title,MultiUsers/Name,MultiUsers/EMail&$expand=MultiUsers";
            $.ajax({
                url: apiPath,
                headers: {
                    Accept: "application/json;odata=verbose"
                },
                async: false,
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data != null) {
                        for (var i = 0; i < data.d.results.length; i++) {
                            console.log(data.d.results[i].Title);
                            for (var j = 0; j < data.d.results[i].MultiUsers.results.length; j++) {
                                console.log(data.d.results[i].MultiUsers.results[j].Name);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                eror: function (data) {
                    console.log("An error occurred. Please try again.");
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
```